# Java Generic Bound Extends Comparable Issue

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

So I have a file that implements a very generic ArrayList interface, and I'm trying to make a second version that implements the Comparable method.
The file would look like this.

```
public class SortedArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements OtherArrayList {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(T t) {...}
}
```

The problem is that I store all my variables within an array of objects where I retrieve them with the method `objectsArray[int i].get()`. 
How do I implement the compareTo method? More specifically, what do I use to get the variable I will be comparing t to?

Comment: `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. You compare `t` to `this`. It is implicit.

Comment: If you intend for `SortedArrayList` itself to be comparable, then you need to write `public class SortedArrayList implements Comparable<SortedArrayList>` and `public int compareTo(SortedArrayList other)`

Comment: `return this.compareTo()` was the way to go, thanks for helping.

Comment: @BeanSpot `return this.compareTo()` is probably recursive and not the way to go.